# Modifying formatting of Table of Contents heading

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, document-classes, thesis

I am finishing up my Master's thesis and need to modify the formatting of the *heading* for the Table of Contents (TOC). My university's guidelines require "TABLE OF CONTENTS" to appear in all caps in the top-center of the page.

I am working with a modified version of the ucthesis.cls template. The original template defines the TOC as:

[Code A]

```
\def\tableofcontents{\@restonecolfalse
  \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi
  \chapter*{\contentsname
       \@mkboth{\uppercase{\contentsname}}{\uppercase{\contentsname}}
  }%
  {\ssp\@starttoc{toc}}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}
```

My workaround to make "TABLE OF CONTENTS" appear correctly has been to rewrite this part of the template as:

[Code B]

```
\def\tableofcontents{\@restonecolfalse
  \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi
  \clearpage
  \begin{center}   
        \MakeUppercase{\contentsname}
  \end{center}
  {\ssp\@starttoc{toc}}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}
```

This works as expected, but removing the `\chapter*{}` line has the side effect of removing indentations before section and subsection numbers in the TOC, as defined by the following lines of code included in the ucthesis.cls template

```
\def\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\def\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
```

Below are the outputs from code snippets A and B, respectively.

[image: Incorrect TOC header, correct indentation]

[image: Correct TOC header, incorrect indentation]

I don't have much experience with LaTeX templates or macros and have found it difficult to dig up some documentation on what things like `\@mkboth` do. If anyone can shed some light on why the TOC needs to be included as a chapter and how I might be able to change the appearance of the header, it would be greatly appreciated--Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

Quick fix:

Redefine `\contentsname`

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
```

and apply a patch to `\@makeschapterhead` locally only for the ToC, that means, when you have to issue `\tableofcontents`, write the lines:

```
{\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}
  {\raggedright}
  {\centering}
  {}
  {}
\tableofcontents
\makeatother}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{ucthesis}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}

\begin{document}

{\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}
  {\raggedright}
  {\centering}
  {}
  {}
\tableofcontents
\makeatother}

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Test}
\section{A section}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following redefinition worked for me:

```
\def\tableofcontents{\@restonecolfalse
  \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi
  %\chapter*{\,%\contentsname
  %     \@mkboth{\uppercase{\contentsname}}{\uppercase{\contentsname}}
  %    }%
  %\clearpage
  \begin{center}
        \MakeUppercase{\contentsname}
  \end{center} \par
  %
  {\ssp\@starttoc{toc}}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}
```

I think the `\par` at the end of the the `\center` environment did the trick. I appreciate the answer, karlkoeller, but I understand this approach a little bit better and it preserves the `\normalsize` font for the TABLE OF CONTENTS header that I need.